# Adjusting column padding in bash

Tags: bash

Any idea how can I put the output as the following?

Input:

```
     1 GATTT
     2 ATCGT
```

Desired output:

```
1      GATTT
2      ATCGT
```

I tried the following and it did not work

```
cut -c7,1-6,8-
```

Comment: Presuming `cut` in the question made this initially an XY question ("I want to do X, and *think* Y is the right tool for the job, but it doesn't work, so I'll ask about my issue with Y", instead of asking about X, which is your *real* problem).

Comment: ...also, to figure out the `cut` issue, we'd need to know details not included in the question (particularly, which of the original whitespace was tab characters, and which was spaces). To show that unambiguously using only functionality built into bash: `IFS= read -r line <input; printf 'line=%q\n' "$line"` -- if you *really* want a `cut` answer, please edit the output from the above (replacing `input` with the name of your real input file) into the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $1,$2}' input

1       GATTT
2       ATCGT
```

or

```
$ awk '{print $1 "\t" $2}' input
```

Comment: That's a possibility, too: `awk -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1}1' input`

Answer (score 0):

SED can also be used:

```
sed  "s/[:digit:]* .*/    &/g" input

1    GATTT
2    ATCGT
```

Comment: I'd suggest `[[:space:]]` rather than a literal space, such that still works even if the whitespace in the original is actually a tab.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the original whitespace were 6 spaces based on your cut command.   The easiest way to knock this out with simple bash commands is using a tab for separation on the output.

```
echo "      1 GATTT" | cut -d ' ' -f 7- | tr ' ' '\t'
```

The cut command makes the delimeter a space character and takes from field 7 on.  Then the tr (translate) command converts the remaining space to a tab.